# What does this eagle symbol/crest mean in Re:Zero?

Tags: re-zero

This symbol is seen on Subaru's cape. Does it represent a lineage or what? Why is Subaru wearing this?

[image]

Update: It's not the same as the symbol on the royal selection insignia/badge:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the same symbol as the one on Emilia's outfit. Was this when Subaru was wearing Emilia's cloak?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot I took is from when Subaru is getting knighted. Maybe it's a symbol that represents "house Emilia" in the royal selection?

Answer (score 0):

As shown below, its the same symbol that hangs in the royal hall. I believe it was also the same symbol on the royal selection badge but I can't find any photos online of that so don't trust me on that.

[image]

Comment: the symbol shown on the wall of your screenshot is the one used for the royal selection insignia/badge (I just added a picture of it to my question) but it's not the same as the one on Subaru's cape

Comment: @JorgeLuque Ah you're right! I spent about a half hour or so looking further and I couldn't seem to find anything. It has an extremely similar design structure to some of the other nation's flags though but they have a different animal. My guess is that it is a nation's insignia. Try posting it on r/Re_Zero on Reddit. I am sure someone there will know. Best of luck!